# POST sqlite databse file to firebase function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, node-sqlite3

I am trying to POST a sqlite db-file (kindle vocab.db) to a firebase cloud function. the function then should read the file and do some stuff. However, it does not work. I am handling the request using express.
The request body's `ContentType` is `multipart/form-data` and one key is the file.

The req.body is a Buffer and looks like this:

```
----------------------------400426499287718202359095
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="db"; filename="vocab.db"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

SQLite format 3   @    W   �                                                                W -�&   �    ����I ��  ... and so on
```

Opening the database throws an exception:

```
  const db = new sqlite3.Database(req.body.toString());
```

```
>  events.js:174 
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>   
>  Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
>  Emitted 'error' event
```

Is it even possible to open a database file like that? If so, does anybody know how?

Comment: Does this SQLite library really read database files as a string? That doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it only takes the filename as a string.
from the [API docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#new-sqlite3databasefilename-mode-callback) :
`filename: Valid values are filenames, ":memory:" for an anonymous in-memory database and an empty string for an anonymous disk-based database. Anonymous databases are not persisted and when closing the database handle, their contents are lost.`

So i guess you can only read a database from a file or create a new in memory one, right?

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation at https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#new-sqlite3databasefilename-mode-callback , the first argument of the constructor can be emptystring for an anonymous disk-based database, `":memory:"` for an anonymous in-memory database, or the filepath to a database file, and turns out that `SQLite format 3   @    W   �                                                                W -�&   �    ����I ��  ... and so on` is not a valid  filepath in your filesystem. seems you are trying to give the database content as a string to the constructor, and that's not legal according to the documentation. write the db to a file first and give the filepath to the constructor instead.